# Whats wrong with char input for this 2 dimensional char array? why its not taking total of K*K inputs?

Tags: c, char, getchar, getch

I am trying to take 2 dimensional char data from user, but it's not taking input from user properly. Could you highlight the bug in following code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
int i, j, k;
char **ch;

printf("\nEnter k : ");
scanf("%d",&k);

ch = (char **) malloc (sizeof(char*) * k );
if(ch == NULL) { printf("\n Not enough memory for ch array "); exit(0);}
for(i = 0; i < k; i++)  {
    ch[i] = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char) * k );
    if(ch[i] == NULL) { printf("\n Not enough memory for ch array "); exit(0);}
}

printf("\nenter char matrix ( %d X %d )\n", k,k);
for(i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        scanf("%c", (*(ch + i) + j) );
    }
}

printf("\n char matrix : \n");
for(i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        printf("%c ",*(*(ch + i) + j));
    }
    printf("\n");
}

for(i = 0; i < k; i++)  free(*(ch + i));
free(ch);   
return 0;
}
```

I tried replacing `char` by `int`. It does work fine for integers.

What's wrong with `char` reading from `stdin`?

Comment: "Please highlight the bug in the following code" -- what do you think this website is, a free debug service? Learn to use a debugger yourself!

Comment: What is the input? What is the expected output? What is the actual output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem:

```
scanf("%c", (*(ch + i) + j) );
```

after `scanf("%d",&k);` there's still a newline in the input buffer, that becomes the first entry of the `char` matrix. If you enter further newlines while filling the matrix, they become matrix entries too.

Clear the input buffer before filling the matrix.

```
int c;
do {
    c = getchar();
}while(c != '\n' && c != EOF);
if (c == EOF) {
    // input stream broken, yell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with this little program until you're comfortable with scanf().  Learn about getchar() and newlines.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char a,b,c;
    scanf("%c", &a);
    scanf("%c", &b);
    scanf("%c", &c);
    printf("a='%c', b='%c', c='%c'\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```